# Change element height in montly Calendar View

Tags: json, calendar-view

I am looking to customize a calendar view in SP Online. My boss requested that the elements shown in the calendar view be bigger, as they take too less space in his opinion.

I am not familiar with JSON, but found a way to change the color of the elements, and figured that adding a font size would force the elements to be bigger.

Here is the code generated by SharePoint :

```
{

  "$schema": https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json,

  "additionalEventClass": {

    "operator": ":",

    "operands": [

      {

        "operator": "<",

        "operands": [

          {

            "operator": "Date()",

            "operands": [

              {

                "operator": "toDateString()",

                "operands": [

                  {

                    "operator": "Date()",

                    "operands": [

                      "[$Date_x0020_de_x0020_d_x00e9_lest]"

                    ]

                  }

                ]

              }

            ]

          },

          {

            "operator": "Date()",

            "operands": [

              {

                "operator": "toDateString()",

                "operands": [

                  {

                    "operator": "Date()",

                    "operands": [

                      "@now"

                    ]

                  }

                ]

              }

            ]

          }

        ]

      },

      "=if(@isSelected == true, 'sp-css-color-WhiteFont sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGreen'+' sp-field-fontSize36' , 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont')+' sp-field-fontSize36'",

      {

        "operator": ":",

        "operands": [

          {

            "operator": ">",

            "operands": [

              {

                "operator": "Date()",

                "operands": [

                  {

                    "operator": "toDateString()",

                    "operands": [

                      {

                        "operator": "Date()",

                        "operands": [

                          "[$Date_x0020_de_x0020_d_x00e9_lest]"

                        ]

                      }

                    ]

                  }

                ]

              },

              {

                "operator": "Date()",

                "operands": [

                  {

                    "operator": "toDateString()",

                    "operands": [

                      {

                        "operator": "Date()",

                        "operands": [

                          "@now"

                        ]

                      }

                    ]

                  }

                ]

              }

            ]

          },

          "=if(@isSelected == true, 'sp-css-color-WhiteFont sp-css-backgroundColor-BgDarkBlue' , 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgLightBlue sp-css-color-LightBlueFont')+' sp-field-fontSizeSmall'",

          ""

        ]

      }

    ]

  }

}
```

And here is the line I added:

```
+' sp-field-fontSize36'
```

Unfortunately, that resulted in nothing happening in calendar view.

Here is an example of what I would like to do (Example title is larger in height than the other elements):
[image: Example of what I would like to do]

How can this be done in SP Online ?

Comment: It cannot be done unfortunately as you can only color cells using JSON formatting for a calendar view at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Christoffer. I will stay tuned for any updates from Sharepoint then.